# android lifecycle event CREATED

Tags: android, android-jetpack

If you follow the link https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/Lifecycle.State.html#CREATED
you'd see that CREATED event is raised in two conditions

1) after onCreate (understandable )
2) right before onStop(wait what ?)

why would the lifecycle raise the CREATED event just before onStop ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, CREATED is not an event but an activity state. The given doc means after onCreate() called, activity is in CREATED (then became RESUMED after onResume() called). When the activity onStop() called, activity became CREATED again (CREATED but not RESUMED in this case).

Comment: makes sense , however can we come up with any reason as to why wont the android team provide us with a separate state of STOPPED to kill the confusion ?.

It sorta appears weird to regard the lifecycle state of an activity as CREATED even when its stopped and also STARTED even when its paused

Comment: Because this "STOPPED" state will be exactly the same with CREATED state. You can understand all these states by considering:
(less active) INITIALIZED -> CREATED -> STARTED -> RESUMED (more active) .  

At last => DESTROYED (dead).

Comment: I think a better explanation is that the activity is destroyed after onStop is called, so it longer can have any state, thus a new instance is created with state = CREATED

Comment: @Phil activity is not destroyed after onStop() call, it just go back to CREATED state. And when user switch to this activity again, it's no need to create another instance of it but just reuse the old one.

Comment: @StoneLam that's not what official Android doc says though : https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/state-changes,

Comment: @Phil  In situation like user press back key or configuration changed, an onDestroy() call comes right after onStop(), then the activity instance will be destroyed. If only onStop() is triggered, like home key is pressed or startActivity() to show another activity, the current one will stay there.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful, you're confusing states with events!

State (Enum values) :CREATED, DESTROYED, INITIALIZED, RESUMED, STARTED

also check this : https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/state-changes

"When a configuration change occurs, the activity is destroyed and recreated. The original activity instance will have the onPause(), onStop(), and onDestroy() callbacks triggered. A new instance of the activity will be created and have the onCreate(), onStart(), and onResume() callbacks triggered."

So given the possible states, CREATED is the one that fit best when onStop is called

Comment: correct. I was confused between the states and events at first. Now however I have a different confusion . What could be the rationale behind not providing a separate state for STOPPED ?

Comment: because the activity is destroyed when onstop is called, so it cannot have a state since it no longer exist